Why Jupyter Notebook in VSCode always clear all outputs when opening a .ipynb document?
Everytime I open a .ipynb document in VSCode, the VSCode always clear all my saved outputs by default. I want to keep all the outputs. I don't know how to turn off this feature. Anyone knows?
The following screenshots are a demo of my situation. My UseDotNetCli.ipynb doc already saved all the outputs. When I open it, all outputs will be cleared automatically. I don't know why. I couldn't find a way to avoid that.


then why are you closing without saving? outputs are part of the notebook content.

@user It because the .ipynb doc already saved all the output. If I save it, all outputs will be actually cleared.
